# How to get all questions with a specific tag between certain dates

Tags: support, api, questions

I would like to get all questions created and tagged with tag "R" between 2 dates.

I'm using parameters: `tagged = R`, `sort = creation`, `fromdate` and `todate` set to appropriate dates and `site = stackoverflow`.

However I get results of length 30 which is the page size and default setting.

Is it possible to get **all** the results using one query or do I need to loop using parameter `page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to *page* through the results. See [the doc page on paging](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging).

So, you would probably want to set the max `pagesize`(100) and then make a sequence of calls. EG:

- `/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=r`
- `/2.2/questions?page=2&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=r`
- `/2.2/questions?page=3&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=r`
- etc.

Be sure to monitor and honor the `backoff`, `error_id`, and `has_more` flags.
(Reference: [*Common Wrapper Object*](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper))