# The /tags query is not giving me the correct results between two dates?

Tags: support, bug, questions, documentation, api-v2.2

I'm trying to get the yearly total number of questions that have the tag `browserify`.

I can see that there are questions tagged from this year like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33852787/371899) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33847320/371899).

The site reports that there are **1491** total questions tagged `browserify`.

When I limit the dates to this year, I get no results.
So I tried querying for questions from before this year, and I get 1491 total questions with the following query created using the [try it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#fromdate=2008-01-01&todate=2015-01-01&order=asc&sort=popular&inname=browserify&filter=!bNKX0pf0ks0Yi6&site=stackoverflow&run=true) page:

```
{
  "count": 9,
  "name": "browserify-rails"
}, {
  "count": 90,
  "name": "browserify-shim"
}, {
  "count": 1491,
  "name": "browserify"
}
```

The information I am getting back from the API seems to be telling me that there are no questions from this year that were tagged with "browserify". Yet I can find questions from this year with the "browserify" tag.

I cannot see where I am going wrong in my usage of the API.

My question is different to ["How to get all questions with a specific tag between certain dates"](https://stackapps.com/q/6636/36874) because the total numbers I see do not match the data I see on the site. I have no issues with paging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sure looks like a bug.

1. Site search shows that [there were 946 `browserify` questions created in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[browserify]%20created%3A2015..2016%20%20is%3Aquestion) (so far).
2. The [/tags route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags) doesn't have a created option, but [it shows 0 questions were active in 2015](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#fromdate=2015-01-01&todate=2016-01-01&order=asc&sort=activity&inname=browserify&filter=!bNKX0pf0ks0Yi6&site=stackoverflow&run=true)!
3. No permutation yielded valid results when trying to specify [any `fromdate` after 2012-05-23 (midnight on the 22nd)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#fromdate=2012-05-23&todate=2016-01-01&order=asc&sort=activity&inname=browserify&filter=!bNKX0pf0ks0Yi6&site=stackoverflow&run=true).  It seems the result is either the total number of `browserify` questions or nothing.
4. Coincidentally, [the earliest question that has the browserify tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10695471/331508) was created on May 22 2012.
   It is plausible that the browserify tag was created that day.

---

So, when specifying a date range with the `/tags` route, the range is for **when the tag was created**.  This is either a bug with the route or an **omission in the documentation**.

---

**Workaround:**
Use the `/search` or the `/search/advanced` routes, with a filter that just returns `total`.
This will give you a correct count of questions, with that tag, in the specified period.

For example,
          [/2.2/search?fromdate=1420070400&todate=1451606400&tagged=browserify](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#fromdate=2015-01-01&todate=2016-01-01&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=browserify&filter=!.UE8F0_CXHtXkIYl&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Gives 946 questions, so far this year -- which is correct.